# validation of viewstate mac failed Exception

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, web-hosting

I have a question and i searched on stack-over flow and found some answer but none of it works for me ,i have a web application it works on the local host but when i host it online it gives me and error that :

```
<customErrors mode="Off" >
```

must be off i made that then i gone to use my application it gives me the following one :

```
Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.
```

any help will be great ,thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lose security benefits by doing this, but the quickest solution would be to set `enableViewStateMac="false"` in the web.config.

```
<pages enableViewStateMac="false" ...>
```

This can sometimes happen if your ViewState is very large, and you postback before the page has finished loading. If you're using ViewState as a data repository, that's probably why this happens. I would also inspect your markup and make sure that you don't have any unclosed `<script>` tags.

Comment: some one told me add this
 <!--<machineKey validationKey="9153F0FB02AA8D613B6E554D1BC8FE5F4C6B74E84B7399BA19F0C222386B2D9A4694A8733848967E43FC65E5980450FD278619D8B1AB74FBCBD8719EA664C6FD" decryptionKey="A9CFFB287F77C30A363AA242CD911BB56314AE2599D859579FAD3C35ED674F94" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />-->

by an online tool that generate this

Comment: You can give that a shot. Just add it somewhere in the `system.web` section, like under the `pages` section for example.